# std::fstream is a class but references std::fstream::trunc using namespace syntax?

Tags: c++, class, static, fstream, qualified-name

I was getting some help on creating files with fstream, but came across this method where you pass std::fstream::trunc to the constructor.

I was curious as to how fstream is a class, but referencing the trunc member is like fstream is a namespace (fstream::trunc, like NAMESPACE::MEMBER).

How is this done?

Comment: If you declare a class `A` with a constructor, in your `.cpp` you already know that you would define that constructor as `A::A(parameters...){ ... }` in your `.cpp` file. If the class has a method named `foo` that returns a `void` that gets declared as `void A::foo(){ // code }` -- doesn't this observation offer a little bit of a clue, here?

Comment: wait then trunc is a function?

Comment: No, but this is not limited to functions, but to anything that's declared in the class. Like a `typedef` or another class, for example.

Comment: i tried int s::something = 3; but that didnt work

Comment: Well, did you declare `something` in your `s` class? What is it?

Answer (score 1):

`trunc` is a static member of the class `std::ios_base`. To access static members you need to use the class name where they are declared or an object of the class.

Here is a demonstration program

```
#include <iostream>

namespace N
{
    class A
    {
    public:
        inline static int x = 10;
    };

    class B : public A
    {
    };
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << N::B::x << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
10
```

Or you could declare the static data member like for example

```
const static int x = 10;
```

or

```
constexpr static int x = 10;
```

Or you could declare it within the class like

```
static int x;
```

and then define it outside the class like

```
int A::x = 10;
```

Comment: i tried to recreate it by doing `class something {static int num=0;};` but i got a compiler error

Comment: @RammyAly Either you declared a local class or used an initializer.

Comment: @RammyAly See the demonstration program in my answer.